# error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/

Tags: docker, filesystems

I am getting the below error message：

> {"changed": false, "msg": "Error creating container: 500 Server Error:
> Internal Server Error ("error creating overlay mount to
> /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e17accf17aa46c9d12dbc4da10e399121b476698039cdcf54a5bb42443ffc260-init/merged:
> invalid argument")"}

docker info shows below：

```
Containers: 0
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
Supports d_type: true
Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Authorization: rhel-push-plugin
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: oci runc
Default Runtime: oci
Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current
containerd version: 1556cce7e5c5349fdffeb123c092a7681769866a (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
runc version: 1556cce7e5c5349fdffeb123c092a7681769866a-dirty (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
init version: N/A (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
seccomp
 WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
 Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
selinux
Kernel Version: 4.18.7-200.fc28.x86_64
Operating System: Fedora 28 (Server Edition)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 2
CPUs: 24
Total Memory: 94.34 GiB
Name: xxxxxx.com
ID: U63T:T7ZF:HWDJ:4NKZ:YUW2:KO6W:7RI5:Y6MY:VKSQ:DJSL:FGD5:QMZS
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: true
Registries: docker.io (secure), registry.fedoraproject.org (secure), quay.io (secure), registry.access.redhat.com (secure), registry.centos.org (secure), docker.io (secure)
```

Here Backing filesystem shows unknown here. How to change it to xfs or somerelevant to work?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/

Answer (score 23):

I was able to resolve this by doing a factory reset in Docker.

Docker for Mac -> Troubleshooting (it is the "bug" icon next to the Settings icon) -> Reset Factory Defaults

Comment: I followed by resetting to factory settings and then I restarted docker after that and used a new terminal tab to build my container using docker-compose

Answer (score 7):

```
$ vim /etc/docker/daemon.json

{

"max-concurrent-uploads": 1

}

$ service docker restart
```

Posting it in case it helps someone.
I had the same issue with the docker. It was not able to push images to GCR. The above was able to solve my issue.

Comment: Would you mind posting your version? The file doesn't seem to exist in docker 19

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you can check the `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` directory using `xfs_info` whether or not it can be supported the `overlay2`.

For instance,

```
$ xfs_info /var/lib/docker/overlay2 | grep ftype
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
```

If the output is `ftype=1`, then it can be supported the `overlay2`.

I hope it help you. :^)

Answer (score 1):

It might happen because daemon.json doesn't exist. For create it you can do following steps: open "Docker Desktop" > "Preferences" > "Docker Engine" > edit the texteditor under "Configure the Docker daemon by typing a json Docker daemon configuration file" > "Apply & Restart".

Answer (score 0):

I have just meet the same issue. And I fixed it by change the disk volume type used by docker into `Ext4` or change the path into a `Ext4` volume by this command in `docker.service`

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph /new-path/docker