# Cannot start my Docker container. Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount

Tags: mysql, docker, server, vps

I have a Docker container running on my VPS. My VPS was restarted few days ago and after that, I'm not able to start my Docker container. I'm getting this error.

```
Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ab89bcddcdc93eclalskqpsa4d50920183ce73c87apqnc8d215e6akspqncvkss/merged: no data available
```

The docker container has a database in it and I haven't make any backup awhile. How can I fix this or at least recover my data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521460/error-creating-overlay-mount-to-var-lib-docker-overlay2)

Comment: @tbhaxor no. It doesn't.