# Error "readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l: invalid argument"

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I'm getting this error when executing `docker run --rm -it alpine /bin/sh`:

> latest: Pulling from library/alpine
> 8921db27df28: Already exists
> Digest: sha256:f271e74b17ced29b915d351685fd4644785c6d1559dd1f2d4189a5e851ef753a
> Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
> ERRO[0040] error waiting for container: context canceled
> docker: Error response from daemon: Failed to inspect container 9919d1156d3960b46bca915bdf3b1d2320f463edbea5c39cacdc8b29640534fe: Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l: invalid argument.

I'm using [Docker Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Adoption) on Windows with WSL 2.

I've tried `docker rmi alpine:latest`, but the error persisted.

I've tried `docker system prune --all`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of workarounds I've used:

1. When using the Docker command line, I specified a different version
   of the image. Instead of *alpine:latest*, I used *alpine:3.16*, and it
   helped.
2. I used [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) instead of WSL 2 (*Docker Desktop* → *Settings* → *General*. Untick "Use the WSL 2 based engine")
3. As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63277395/19541281), I reset Docker WSL 2 data. But
   instead of resetting all Docker data, it is possible to clear only
   WSL 2: *Docker Desktop* → *Troubleshoot* (it is the "bug" icon next to
   the *Settings* icon) → *Clean/Purge data*, select *WSL 2*, and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.